# Solve:$z^7+az^3+2b$

Tags: complex-numbers

In my script a complex number is defined like that:
$z^7+az^3+2b$
if ($z=-1+i$) is a root, find ($a+b=?$)

Comment: What have you tried? What do you get when you substitute $z = -1+i$ into the expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $z^4=-4$ is real, so that 
 $$z^8+az^4+2bz=0$$

immediately implies $$b=0.$$

Then

$$a=-z^4=4.$$

Comment: How to $Z^4=-4$ ??

Comment: @StackExchangecontributor: what is $z^2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $z^2 =-2i$ so $$z^7 = 8i(-1+i)=-8-8i$$

and $$z^3 = -2i(-1+i)=2+2i$$  Plug this in to your equation and voila...